# docstring(myClass.aProperty) does not return the docstring for aproperty

Tags: python, docstring

Below is a sketch of a class I want to document.
My first wish is to get short help from within Jupyter.

**These help calls work as I expected:**

help(thermo): showing everything (class, methods and properties)

help(thermo.select): showing the select help

help(thermo.table): showing the table help

**Unfortunately, this one doesn't work as I would expect:**

help(thermo.take)  does not return the help from the take property.

Instead, this statement returns all the attributes from the take object. (2000+)

Could you clarify what happens,
and suggest me how to get help(thermo.take)  working as I would like?

Thanks

```
class substances(list, metaclass=substancesMeta):
    ''' A thermodynamic database of substances '''
    @property
    def take(self):
        ''' A simple way to take a substance. '''

    def select(self, ... ):
        ''' Select a subset of the database. '''

    def table(self, **kwargs):
        ''' Create a pandas dataframe from substances object '''
```

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that  `take` is a property rather than a method of `substances`.

Comment: *"how to get help(thermo.take) working as I would like"* - you can't. The point of the descriptor protocol is that the result of accessing `thermo.take` is whatever the getter returns.

Comment: Should I then add a metaclass to the Take class? (but I don't see right know  how to take advantage of it)

Answer (score 0):

The point of properties is that `thermo.take` gets you the object returned by the getter (in this case, a `Take` object). That's why `help(thermo.take)` is equivalent to `help(Take())` (or whatever your "take object" is).

You can bypass this behavior by calling `help` on the property of the class:

```
help(substances.take)
# Or
help(type(thermo).take)
```

This works because there's no `self` upon which you're calling `take`, so the only thing it has to return is your defined property.